# Fluent NHibernate mapping

Tags: .net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I've inserted value into Make and Models table. But the Ids in both tables are showing in Even and Odd number.

The Id column suppose to .GeneratedBy.Identity(); as (1,2,3,4.......) in both the parent and child tables Id column.

```
MAKE
ID | Name
-----------
1  | BMW
3  | Mercedes

MODELS
ID | Name | MakeID
------------------
 2 | Ex  | 1
 4 | Lx  | 3
```

How to fix this problem to avoid inserting Even or Odd numbers into parent and child tables.

```
public MakeMap()
{
    Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();
    Map(x => x.Name);
    HasMany<Models>(x => x.Models).Cascade.All().KeyColumn("MakeId");
    Table("Make");
}

public ModelsMap()
{
    Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();
    Map(x => x.Name);
    References<Make>(x => x.Make).Column("MakeId");                
    Table("Models");
}
```

Any help will greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: That shouldn't happen. Did you have a look at the SQL being generated?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that this is being caused by your mapping? I don't know what database you are using, but is it possible that your Identity Specification (using SQL Server as an example) is set up to increment by 2?